# TypedQuery serviceHub.withEntityManager returns consumed states

Tags: corda

My question is similar to [serviceHub.vaultQueryService.queryBy returns all related states by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45144809/servicehub-vaultqueryservice-queryby-returns-all-related-states-by-default) except we have schemas mapped for states and use TypedQueries to fetch states from database.

The flow which queries a state from database:

```
@StartableByRPC
@Transactional
open class FetchServiceById(
    private val serviceId: UniqueIdentifier
) : FlowLogic<List<ServiceSchemaV1.PersistentService>>() {

    @Suspendable
    override fun call(): List<ServiceSchemaV1.PersistentService> {

        return serviceHub.withEntityManager {
            createQuery(
                "SELECT s FROM $TABLE_NAME s WHERE s.linearId = ?1",
                ServiceSchemaV1.PersistentService::class.java
            ).setParameter(
                1,
                serviceId.id
            ).resultList
        }
    }

    private companion object {
        val TABLE_NAME = ServiceSchemaV1.PersistentService::class.jvmName
    }
}
```

This returns a state correctly but after updating the particular state and running query again it returns both the old, consumed state and the new unconsumed state.

I checked the h2 database and can see that after a state update, in VAULT_STATE there is a date in CONSUMED_TIMESTAMP and its STATE_STATUS is 1.

How can we only query unconsumed states with typed queries? I know we could just use linearquery but when we need to query and join data from different states I don't think that would be computationally feasible.

The schema the state uses

```
object ServiceSchema

object ServiceSchemaV1 : MappedSchema(
    schemaFamily = ServiceSchema.javaClass,
    version = 1,
    mappedTypes = listOf(
        PersistentService::class.java
    )) {
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "service_states")

    class PersistentService(
        @Column(name = "accountoperator")
        var accountOperator: String,

        @Column(name = "serviceprovider")
        var serviceProvider: String,

        @Column(name = "servicename")
        var serviceName: String,

        @Column(name = "servicedescription")
        var serviceDescription: String,

        @Column(name = "datacreated")
        var dataCreated: LocalDate,

        @Column(name = "linear_id")
        var linearId: UUID,

        @ElementCollection
        @Column(name = "service_data_ids")
        var serviceDataIds: MutableList<UUID>,

        @ElementCollection
        @Column(name = "service_partners")
        var servicePartners: MutableList<String>

    ) : PersistentState() {
        constructor() : this(
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            LocalDate.now(),
            UUID.randomUUID(),
            mutableListOf(),
            mutableListOf()
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could perform a join query on your State's Schema and the VAULT_STATE table on the basis of the TRANSACTION_ID  and OUTPUT_INDEX and filter based on STATE_STATUS.

```
Select X, Y Z, from MY_STATE M, VAULT_STATES V WHERE M.TRANSACTION_ID = 
V.TRANSACTION_ID AND M.OUTPUT_INDEX = V.OUTPUT_INDEX AND STATE_STATUS = 0
```

Comment: Thanks, I guess that's the only way to do it

Answer (score 0):

You should check that all the necessary parties are included for the service call. Otherwise you can only see the states the particular node was included with the last state update's contract.